# Runtime Error: this.userprovider.userSignup(...).subscribe is not a function in Ionic

Tags: angular, mongodb, ionic-framework

Below is signup.ts

I wanted to insert the data in MongoDB. 
I'm getting the error like

> this.userprovider.userSignup(...).subscribe is not a function.

Please help me to solve the error

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic- 
angular';
import { UserProvider } from '../../providers/user/user';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html',
})

export class SignupPage {

  private registerUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/signup';
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  repassword: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public userprovider: UserProvider) {
  }

  signup(): void {

    let review = {
      username: this.username,
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
      repassword: this.repassword
    };
    console.log(review);

    this.userprovider.userSignup(review).subscribe(

      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      error => {
        //this.loading = false;
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Below is provider/user.ts
this file is provider file. I used subscribe here. but it creates problems..so what is the solution

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UserProvider {
  data: any;
  private registerUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/signup';

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.data = null;
  }

  userSignup(review): any {

    return this.http.post(this.registerUrl, review)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res.json());
      });
  }
}
```

As you can see I have tried to solve the error in my way.Anyone that maybe knows how I can solve this?

Comment: sajeetharan's answer explain the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the response from the service. Since you are subscribing to the observable from the component, No need to subscribe it from the service.

```
userSignup(review):Observable<any>{

  return this.http.post(this.registerUrl, review);
}
```

Comment: thanks.above error is solved but i have another question is how to insert the data in mongodb ..i have server.ts ready ..

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here,

(i) You can subscribe only to an observable, change your return type as,

```
userSignup(review):Observable<any>
```

(ii) You should use subscribe only within your component, not inside the service method. So change your method as,

```
userSignup(review):Observable<any>{
  return this.http.post(this.registerUrl, review);
}
```